# Why does sender behave as if it has been passed as byref?

Tags: vb.net

isnt sender passed as byval? If so then why does the sender object behave as if it's been passed as byref. We were able to change the button text on the button sender apparently reffered to in the code below.

```
Private Sub Button_Click(byval sender As Object,byval  e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click
    DirectCast(sender, Button).Text = "You clicked me!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A copy of the reference to the sender object is passed into the method. This means when you change the text, you are changing it on the same object. I suggest you go read this wonderful article by Jon Skeet: 
[Parameters](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so basically it behaves the same way as it would have, had we have passed it as reference?

Comment: No - go read the article for a great explanation on the difference.

Comment: Particularly the section under "
Sidenote: what is the difference between passing a value object by reference and a reference object by value?"

Comment: OK, I will read the article. But it's a C# article. I do know that the same concept apply to both languages, but I have to use a converter since I don't know C#. Is there a vb.net article on this?

Comment: @MarkHennery: Passing by reference allows you to assign or re-assign a new instance to the parameter and have this persist as an assignment to the argument after the method call. Passing by value does not allow an assignment to the parameter to result in an assignment to the argument after the method call.

Answer (score 1):

ByVal sends a copy when you use a primitive, string, or structure (Boolean, integer, dateline, etc.).
When you send in an object, it is not copied, but its reference is copied. Therefore you work with same object. Button is an object.